# How to detect event when reach ScrollView bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to detect event  MyScrollView reach bottom.

like Listview code

```
getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (totalItemCount == firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) {// reach scroll bottom
}
```

how to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Detecting When ScrollView Hits Bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953692/android-detecting-when-scrollview-hits-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953692/android-detecting-when-scrollview-hits-bottom)  may help You to find the last position in a scroll view.You can try this for now