# how can I make footer visible,only if ScrollView is scrolled down?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, android-scroll, android-scrollbar

If the `ScrollView` is scrolled down it has to show the footer. If its scrolled up, then footer has to disable. how to do this kinda stuff?

Comment: show us what you already tried.

Comment: Is that a scrollView or listView

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953692/android-detecting-when-scrollview-hits-bottom When you get to the bottom you could show your bottom view

Comment: @EmilAdz I haven't tried. Just asking a suggestion so that I can implement

Comment: @Gyonder checking it...

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted this in the comment already but here it is anyway.

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));
        if( diff <= 0 ){ 
            yourFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            yourFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```

Extend ScrollView and then override the onScrollChanged method.